# Pyramid and FormAlchemy admin interface

Tags: python, authorization, acl, pyramid, formalchemy

I have a pyramid project using the formalchemy admin interface. I added the basic ACL authentication and the pyramid_formalchemy plugin always denys even though I am authenticated.

Any thoughts on how only allow authenticated users to use the pyramid_formalchemy admin interface?

The authorization policy was add like this:

```
authn_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy('MYhiddenSECRET', callback=groupfinder)
authz_policy = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()

config = Configurator(
   settings=settings,
   root_factory='package.auth.RootFactory',
   authentication_policy=authn_policy,
   authorization_policy=authz_policy
)

# pyramid_formalchemy's configuration
config.include('pyramid_formalchemy')
config.include('fa.jquery')
config.formalchemy_admin('admin', package='package', view='fa.jquery.pyramid.ModelView')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`pyramid_formalchemy` uses the permissions `'view', 'edit', 'delete', 'new'` to determine who can do what. The `__acl__` is propagated down from your SQLAlchemy model object. Thus, you need to put an `__acl__` on each of your model objects allowing your desired groups access to those permissions. For example, from the `pyramid_formalchemy` `pyramidapp` example project:

```
class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bar'
    __acl__ = [
            (Allow, 'admin', ALL_PERMISSIONS),
            (Allow, 'bar_manager', ('view', 'new', 'edit', 'delete')),
        ]
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo = Column(Unicode(255))
```

Of course, if you do not supply an `__acl__` then it will look in the lineage of the resource tree until it hits the `factory`. By default, `pyramid_formalchemy` defines its own factory `pyramid_formalchemy.resources.Models`, however you can subclass this and provide an `__acl__` to it, as a global for all of your models:

```
from pyramid_formalchemy.resources import Models

class ModelsWithACL(Models):
    """A factory to override the default security setting"""
    __acl__ = [
            (Allow, 'admin', ALL_PERMISSIONS),
            (Allow, Authenticated, 'view'),
            (Allow, 'editor', 'edit'),
            (Allow, 'manager', ('new', 'edit', 'delete')),
        ]

config.formalchemy_admin('admin', package='package', view=..., factory=ModelsWithACL)
```