# mixing url dispatch and traversal

Tags: python, pyramid

I've been working on an app that uses url dispatch.  I setup my root factory based on some great info found here: https://github.com/mmerickel/pyramid_auth_demo (thanks Michael!)

Now I'm trying to use pyramid_formalchemy as well.  It seems pyramid_formalchemy uses traversal for determining authorization.  That's ok, but I'm stuck on one point...

For traversal objects need to be location-aware which means they need to have a name and parent.  So I have a User object.

```
class User(Base):
    __name__ = 'user'
    __parent__ = ...
```

I've defined my desired ACLs in my RootFactory.  This all gets setup when the RootFactory's constructor gets called.  I'd like to set all my classes' parents to the RootFactory, but create a RootFactory instance you need to pass in a request to the constructor (particularly because my RootFactory subclasses pyramid_formalchemy.resources.Models)

But when setting up my classes I don't have a request.

How can I correctly set **parent** on my classes to RootFactory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered some similar questions on handling ACLs within pyramid_formalchemy here:

[Pyramid and FormAlchemy admin interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671300/pyramid-and-formalchemy-admin-interface/5678806#5678806)

Basically pyramid_formalchemy defines it's own root factory for all of the admin URLs. You can override it and define an `__acl__` there (see `ModelsWithACL`) which will probably solve most of your problems. From that root, pyramid_formalchemy will automatically setup the `__parent__` references. So if you define some special `__acl__` on your object, that will be tested first, then the `ACLAuthorizationPolicy` will look at the `__parent__` which would be the `Models` or `ModelsWithACL` object.

See also:

http://docs.formalchemy.org/pyramid_formalchemy/#setting-permissions

Comment: Yeah I saw this answer before.  The problem I'm still facing is that the pyramid_formalchemy machinery is not setting the __parent__ property on my models.  So when a model becomes the context and the authorization policy moves up the lineage, ACLAuthorizationPolicy.permits() bottoms out on the model itself and never makes it to my custom RootFactory.  Where does pyramid_formalchemy set the __parent__ on the models?

Comment: I see the code now in Models.__getitem__()  You're right this does setup __parent__ on the model.  Viewing pages like .../admin/User works and users are listed.  What's broken is the .../admin page itself.  It should be listing all the models I configured in the call to formalchemy_admin().  But when the /admin page is called __getitem__() is never called and so the __parent__ for the models is not set correclty and I don't see the models listed.